# AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL http://+:8080/api/ - how to: "netsh http add urlacl" programatically from .NET Process?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, netsh, self-host-webapi

I'm working on a project in .NET Framework 4.6.1, C# and WinForms (offline desktop app).
I come from web-dev and I'm not very familiar with desktop apps.

For part of the app, I am using `HttpSelfHostServer` to give me API functionality.

```
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080/api/");

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*"));

        // pass in config to new server instance
        HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);

        server.OpenAsync().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

This throws an error: `AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL http://+:8080/api/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace`

I have tried:

1. Use the `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/api/ user=everyone` command from the CMD as Administrator which fixes the issue but this is a bad solution. The end-user of the app should not have to use the command line.
2. Programatically run the above command:

   ```
        var netshProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = "cmd",
                Arguments = "netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/api/ user=everyone",
                UseShellExecute = true,
                Verb = "runas",

                //WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            }
        };

        try
        {
            netshProcess.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception portRegisterError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(portRegisterError);
            throw;
        }
   ```

According to similar issues that I have found this should execute the command with Admin rights but all it does in my case is:  opens Windows User Acces Control to confirm, then opens the command prompt window with no commands passed in (resulting in throwing the same `AddressAccessDeniedException`).

What am I missing?

I know that all this may seem like a 'hacky' way to do things but for various reasons, I do not have much choice in this and I just have to make this work one way or another without asking the end-user to do stuff.

I'd apriaciate any advice.

Many thanks.

Comment: It's not clear when / where the code you posted is supposed to run. + You have a `Console.ReadLine();` there. When / where is the server created? There's nothing related to a WinForms app here. If you need to run your WinForms app elevated, there's an `app.manifest` setting for that. While debugging, Visual Studio also needs to run elevated, otherwise you won't be able to register the server. -- It looks like you're trying to run the server in `Program.cs`, treating it as a Console app and without storing a reference to the server or using a Controller -- I'd pick a port other than `8080`.

Comment: BTW, try not to write async stuff like this: `server.OpenAsync().Wait();` in a WinForms app, you'll regret it soon enough (maybe not in the VS IDE, but when the app is run for real). Always await you async calls. Main can also be async: `static async Task Main(string[] args)` -- Check this self-hosting helper:  [ASP.NET Core Self-Hosting with a .NET 5 Windows Forms App - GitHub](https://github.com/tonysneed/Demo.DotNetSelfHost)

Comment: Hi Jimi, thank you for yor reply. I know all of this is not ideal but I was not given any choice (I also can not use NET 5). All I am trying to do is to run cmd command elevated from within my app code: `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/api/ user=everyone` - is this possible?. It works ok when I do this directley from windows cmd treminal (as admin) but it does not work from my C# code.  The code that tries to run cmd command to register the url is ran before creation the server. Thanks.

Comment: That library I linked is to provide some clues. It doesn't matter whether you're using .Net 5 or .Net Framework, the procedure is all the same. What is missing here is the initialization procedure, as a whole. As mentioned, it's not clear at all what you're doing, when and where. You're not giving any context to the operations, as if you pasted in random code made for a Console app. -- As mentioned, you need an elevated application AND and elevated VS IDE, for testing and debugging.

Comment: You are missing `/c` for cmd.exe to execute the netsh command and terminate. See the [cmd.exe docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd).